# Trigger Best Practice Question

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 3 custom objects.

```
Expense__c (Parent)

ExpenseChild__c (Child)

ExpenseGChild__c (Grand Child)
```

All the relationships between a parent and its immediate child is M-D.

I have built the following trigger that will perform an update in Expense__c (Parent) when the grand children records (ExpenseGChild__c) are updated.

The following code works but I am not sure whether what I have written is in line with the best practices.

Can someone take a look and let me know if the code can be improved further ?

Trigger on Grand Child(ExpenseGChild__c)

```
trigger GChildTrigger on ExpenseGChild__c (before insert,before update) {

    if(Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
    List<ExpenseGChild__c> egc = Trigger.new;
    List<ExpenseChild__c> ec = new List<ExpenseChild__c>();
    List<Expense__c> e = new List<Expense__c>();
    Set<Id> ExpenseChild_Temp = new Set<Id>();

    for(ExpenseGChild__c egci : egc)
    {
       ec.add(new ExpenseChild__c(Id = egci.ExpenseChild__c,TriggerField__c = egci.TriggerField__c));
       ExpenseChild_Temp.add(egci.ExpenseChild__c);
    }  

    update ec;

    List<ExpenseChild__c> Temp_List = [SELECT ID,Expense__c,Expense__r.Type__c,TriggerField__c from ExpenseChild__c WHERE ID IN :ExpenseChild_Temp];


    for(ExpenseChild__c eci : Temp_List)
    {
        e.add(new Expense__c(Id = eci.Expense__c,Type__c = eci.TriggerField__c));
        System.debug('Id : '+eci.Expense__c+' Triggerfield : '+eci.TriggerField__c);
    }
    update e;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible you must use formula fields to achieve this. If that is not possible for some reason, here are is the trigger which you should use.

```
trigger GChildTrigger on ExpenseGChild__c (before insert,before update) {

    if(Trigger.isUpdate)// Do you really want to achieve this only on update? & not on insert? May be change this to - if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
    //List<ExpenseGChild__c> egc = Trigger.new; //variable is waste of memory 
    List<ExpenseChild__c> ec = new List<ExpenseChild__c>();
    //List<Expense__c> e = new List<Expense__c>();
    //Set<Id> ExpenseChild_Temp = new Set<Id>();

    for(ExpenseGChild__c egci : Trigger.New)//Used Trigger.New in place of  egc
    {
       ec.add(new ExpenseChild__c(Id = egci.ExpenseChild__c,TriggerField__c = egci.TriggerField__c));
       //ExpenseChild_Temp.add(egci.ExpenseChild__c);
    }  

    update ec;


    //This code should be in Trigger for ExpenseChild__c
    /*
    List<ExpenseChild__c> Temp_List = [SELECT ID,Expense__c,Expense__r.Type__c,TriggerField__c from ExpenseChild__c WHERE ID IN :ExpenseChild_Temp];


    for(ExpenseChild__c eci : Temp_List)
    {
        e.add(new Expense__c(Id = eci.Expense__c,Type__c = eci.TriggerField__c));
        System.debug('Id : '+eci.Expense__c+' Triggerfield : '+eci.TriggerField__c);
    }
    update e;

    */
 }
```